# l3regex replace multiplication with cdot

Tags: l3regex

I am trying to use a combination of Latex and sage to create tasks for my pupils.
Therefore I have to replace two different types of expressions

`2*x`  shall become `2 x`

and

`x*3` shall become `x\cdot 3`

```
\documentclass[utf8,fleqn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{l3regex}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { 2*x-x*4 }
\regex_replace_all:nnN { [a-z]\*\d+ } { \1 \c{cdot} \2 } \l_my_tl

$\l_my_tl$

\end{document}
```

This gives me `2*x-\cdot` instead of `2*x-x\cdot 4`

My question is, how can I refer to the separate matches found by `l3regex`?

Comment: You shouldn't pile up new questions. Please, make a new one and roll back this one to the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to capture the matches: this is standard for any regex, not just for the `expl3` engine

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { 2*x-x*4 }
\regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-z])\*(\d+) } { \1 \c{cdot} \2 } \l_my_tl
$\l_my_tl$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've not explicitly loaded `l3regex` as it was made part of the `expl3` core some time ago

Answer (score 2):

You can transform “letter *” into “letter `\cdot`” and then get rid of the remaining asterisks.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { 2*x-x*4 }
\regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-z])\*(\d+) } { \1 \c{cdot} \2 } \l_tmpa_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { \* } { } \l_tmpa_tl

$\l_tmpa_tl$

\end{document}
```